# solr - wrong cord similiraty value

Tags: java, solr

I have a field:

`<field name="name" type="nameType" indexed="true" multiValued="false" stored="true"/>`

and type:

`<fieldType name="nameType" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>`

There are two documents:

Doc1 : `{"name":"one"}`

Doc2 :`{"name":"one two"}`

Now if I query `"name:one two"` the **first result is Doc1** which is obviously wrong. I debugged my query and noticed that they have the same `coord value = (1/2)` . Why is that? It should be 1 for Doc2.

As far as I know the coord value is number of query terms (tokens) ,which matched indexed field, divided by all query tokens. To make sure I checked my type in analysis section in solar dashboard and "one two" is divided into two tokens "one", "two" while indexing and querying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases only the "one" token is going to be matched so the coord=(1/2) that you mention is correct.

The "one" token of the query is matched against the name field of the documents, while the "two" token is matched against the default field that you have specified in your solr schema (which does not exist in any of your documents and thereby it is not matched).

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can you further explain or provide resource why query "two" token is not going to be matched against name field?

Comment: Assuming that you are using the default Lucene query parser you can have a look at the following resource(https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Fields) that explains why the "two" token of your query will be matched against the default field (and not the name field).

Comment: Thanks! That was it. I forgot to surround term with " ".